# Strange interaction between module and attribute sets

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, magento2.4, attribute-set, gift-card

I faced an unusual problem on one of the live sites. The gift card module adds its "Gift Card by Amasty" option in the "Add product" menu and when the module behaves normally, it page looks like this:

[image: clean test Magento]

(This is a completely clean Magento for tests with the same versions, with only the gift card module installed)

But for some reason on the live site gift card creation looks different:
[image: live site]
[image: live site]

The usual set of product attributes is loaded at the top of the form, while the attribute group I need is loaded separately at the bottom of the page and with empty fields for some reason. I understand that this is some sort of bug with attribute sets, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I did a little research:

- Changes in existing attribute sets do not change anything
- There are no errors in the logs
- Disabling the rest of the non-Magento modules didn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was, most likely the module was installed on live on an earlier module version and was updated by the composer. The script that added the data for the attributes did not work during the update. I deleted the module row from the **setup_module** table and compiled again and it worked